# Hide panel dropdown in grafana

Tags: javascript, iframe, panel, grafana

How can I hide/remove the dropdown which appears on hovering mouse on panels when viewing in `kiosk` mode. Below are the screenshots of dropdown which I want to hide.

I am working on a forked `grafana` with my custom panel plugins. I can remove it directly from the `grafana` code as I am working on forked `grafana` but I want to remove that only when viewing it from `kiosk` mode.

Right now I implemented that using post messages which I send to `iframe` of grafana. This solution has lots of problems and I want to avoid it.

[image: Dropdown in panel header with title]

[image: Dropdown in panel header without title]